# Distribute Points on Face to Objects with Particle Properties

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to distribute the cylinder on the face of the icosphere that has some particle properties. When I tried to joint geometries, the particles properties disappeared. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe try switching the order of the links going into the join geometry.  Anyway, what attributes are disappearing?

Comment: did you try realize instances before distribute on points? if that doesn't help, pls provide blend file

Comment: realize instances node solved the problem! Thanks @Chris